# Parseval to find length

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, parsevals-identity

> Use Parsevals identity to find the length
>
> $$|f| = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[f(x)]^{2}dx}$$
>
> for $f(x) = 2 \cos(14x) + 4 \cos(11x) + 2 \sin(27x) - \cos(19x) + 5 \cos(140x)$.

So I'm a bit confused as to which side of the equation to work on-- as trying to square $f(x)$ is not something that seems overly fun. However, I am aware that the function can be reduced and rewritten as a Fourier series, but I also don't think that's entirely correct because it is such a complex function to begin with. As someone who is quite new to linear algebra and therefore does not necessarily have a whole grasp on this, can somebody help me and walk me through how to do this?

Comment: Do you know that if $f(x)$ is in the form:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cos(nx)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n\sin(nx)$$
Then the following holds:
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)^2~dx=\frac{1}{2}a_0^2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n^2+b_n^2)$$

Comment: Yes, but how do I get it into the fourier series form?

Comment: It already is in that form. Note that all $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s are zero except $a_{14}=2$, $a_{11}=4$, $b_{27}=2$, $a_{19}=-1$ and $a_{140}=5$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, $f(x)$ as given to you is already in Fourier series form, so no need to reduce and rewrite. A real-valued Fourier series on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is a sum of terms of the form $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$, and all your terms are already in that form. So $f$ is just a Fourier series where all but $5$ of the coefficients are zero.

Comment: So, essentially, it is the sum of the squared terms of each of the coefficients? (2,4,2,-1,5)?

Comment: @MorganO Yes -- actually the square root of the sum of the squared coefficients is what the question asks for.